# How to avoid refresh of layout view when navigating between pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

If I have a more than one pages, all using the same layout page, is there a way I can navigate between the pages and only refresh the body part of the layout page. For example if I have a list page and select an item to go to the detail page and they both contain the same layout view, I don't want the layout which contains the menu and footer to reload, just the  @RenderBody() should reload.
I am building this in Mvc 3.
I am a beginner to Mvc so help we with some examples.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't we use Updatepanel or something similar in Mvc

Answer (score 0):

Call the pages in ajax and replace the content of your html body

Tutorial: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/02/how-to-supercharge-your-sites-speed-with-ajax-and-jquery/

Demo: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/cdn-origin/uploads7/how-to-supercharge-your-sites-speed-with-ajax-and-jquery/demo2/#page3